# What this error mean in high-order function? [Scala]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I need to write code only in functional way

This is what my code looks like:

```
val sqrt = (x: Double) => x*x
val doubleValue = (x: Double) => 2*x

val yoman = (list: List[Double], func: Function[Double, Double]) => list match {
case _ => func(list.head)
case Nil => list
}

yoman(1. :: 5. :: Nil, sqrt)
yoman(2. :: -6. :: Nil, doubleValue)
```

Function have to return list

It returns an error:

Error:(9, 80) ')' expected but integer literal found.
def get$$instance$$res0 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ yoman(1. :: 5. :: Nil, sqrt)

The arrow like this "^" is under "generated" word at last line

Comment: `sqrt` usually stands for "square root" but your function returns a square.

Comment: What is `2.::` supposed to do? When you call methods using `.`, you must supply the arguments in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, scala does not like constructing ints as doubles with `::`,**

```
scala> val doubles1: List[Double] = 1 :: 5 :: Nil
                                      ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[AnyVal]
        required: List[Double]
```

while you can build `List[Double]` using constructor `List(int1, int2)`

```
scala> val doubles1: List[Double] = List(1, 5)
doubles1: List[Double] = List(1.0, 5.0)
```

or specify values as double,

```
scala> val doubles1: List[Double] = 1d :: 5d :: Nil
doubles1: List[Double] = List(1.0, 5.0)
```

**Your hof looks good but you might want to update your pattern match as first match `_` in your example will match all universe of cases.**
It will explode when you pass in empty `List`,

```
yoman(List.empty[Double], doubleValue) // throws java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
```

update to check if the list is non empty before trying to take head element.

```
val sqrt = (x: Double) => x * x
val doubleValue = (x: Double) => 2 * x

val yoman = (list: List[Double], func: Function[Double, Double]) => list match {
  case head :: _ => func(head)
  case Nil => list
}

val doubles1: List[Double] = 1d :: 5d :: Nil
val doubles2: List[Double] = 1d :: 5d :: Nil

println(yoman(doubles1, sqrt)) //1.0
println(yoman(doubles2, doubleValue)) //2.0
```

Might also be helpful: [Implicit conversion from List[Int] to List[Double] fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061166/432903)

Comment: Thank you so much for so detailed explanation) Now I know the difference between list types.

Comment: Maybe you can help me, how can I make a recursion that will be returning a list, like a result of this function. I thought that it have to look like this: 

"""""" case head :: tail => func(head) :: yoman(tail, func) """"""         

But I catch an error:
Error:(5, 39) recursive lazy value yoman needs type
  case head :: tail => func(head) :: yoman(tail, func)
  
"^" is under func(head).
But when I`m changing second element of concatenation to similar tail or list.tail which I think is the same, it returns me the list but with modified only 1 element, as expected